# Should the most important page for SEO be my homepage?

Tags: seo, ranking, homepage

I have a website that over time has accumulated a few hundred links, mainly on the homepage. It markets an iPhone app and we didn't optimize it for SEO. Recently, we launched a more professional tool on the site for businesses, where SEO is critical. That other page is better optimized and starts to rank better but has a lot less external links than the homepage (less than 10 root domains point to that other page, even though it gets internal links from almost all pages on my site).

Do you think I should move that page to my homepage to rank better?

Answer (score 1):

Many websites have a homepage ranking better than internal webpages because the homepage usually have more backlinks. However, Google ranks webpages one by one and can consider that an internal webpage has a better ranking than a homepage.

If you want to see you homepage ranking better, you can optimize it for SEO. Otherwise, having an internal webpage ranking better than the homepage is not a problem for SEO.

Comment: Thanks. Actually I don't mind about the homepage ranking better. What I'm wondering is if I would be better off swapping the content of my internal page with the homepage to get more visits on that new homepage. In other terms, am I using my website at its full potential by having my most important internal page rarely linked to directly.

Comment: The most important is your visitor arrives to your website (whatever the webpage, a visit is a visit) and he must find the information he's looking for according to keywords he typed on Google.